# Generate Macular Grid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, automatic-ref-counting, geometry, easeljs

How to generate macular grid in Javascript? In Macular grid contains a no.of circles that should in 'V' shape format.

Creation of dotted circles in 'V' shape? let us know how to resolve this?

To Identify the Macular grid shape, please refer the below link i have added a screenshot.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0uzfyuzednuldi4/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-27%20at%208.04.47%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Out of curiosity. Does this some how relates do [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macular_degeneration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macular_degeneration)? If not can you post a reference? Is the second time in this month I see a question about this subject but could not find anything different from that.

Comment: Okay i'll send a screen shot for macular generation

Comment: Prusse, I have updated my question, please let us know about this pattern style.

Comment: So you want to draw an image like you example?

Comment: Yes exactly.. I am expecting that answer, atleast if u have any references let us know

Comment: Did you try any thing?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried to display the shape.. am able to get circle shape only.. not get the expected output

Comment: This is homework/school project? Can you show your code displaying the circle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort show to learn the basic concepts involved have been show.

Comment: Prusse, Here we are using easel js it's latest techonology. Here am implementing many no.of. pattern styles using easel js concepts. what did u mean by basic concept. what you are expecting from this question?

Comment: Can't understand your core problem. It is draw more than one shape, draw some circles in some pattern or an algorithm to create a pattern similar to your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output for MacularGrid B:

```
 jsfiddle.net/jyoshna/tcgefwen/2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of this graph type, nor can I find info. If this is mathematically derived, then I would be interested to find out how it works.

Rules I observed:

1. The rings reduce their point count in a linear fashion. 20, 16, 12, 8.
2. Each alternate ring is offset by 1/2 of the iterative angle. For example, if they are every 20 degrees in an alternate row, then it would be offset by 10 degrees.
3. The diagram doesn't appear to space the rings evenly, but I think that was the intent.

**So here is my attempt:**
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/sbmaLed1/

1. The main function allows a radius (of the outer ring)
2. You can specify the number of circles in the outer ring, and inner ring
3. You can then specify the degeneration (sorry for poor naming, my initial function worked in reverse). This is supposed to be the number of dots to increment each ring. You NEED 4 in order to get your effect. You can vary it up to get some interesting effects though (http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/sbmaLed1/3/)

Here is the main function:

```
function drawMac(radius, start, end, degenerate) {
    var g = new createjs.Graphics().f("#f00").dc(0,0,5);
    for (var i=start, l=end; i<=l; i+=degenerate) {
        var segments = i; // Easier to read than "i"
        var d = segments/end * radius;
        var counter = segments%(degenerate*2) == 0;
        var offset = Math.PI*2 * 1/segments;
        for (var j=0; j<segments; j++) {
            var angle = Math.PI*2 * (j/segments);
            var s = new createjs.Shape(g);
            s.x = Math.sin(angle) * d;
            s.y = Math.cos(angle) * d;
            container.addChild(s);
        }
    }
    container.rotation = 45; // Cuz it looks cooler
}
```

Hope this helps. It was kind of fun to figure this out.

## [EDIT]

I made some small adjustments, and got it much closer:

1. Trended towards the outside (see the Math.pow addition)
2. Added slight rotation trend towards the middle (see the +0.002 in the angle)

Here is the final function:

```
function drawMac(radius, start, end, degenerate) {
    var g = new createjs.Graphics().f("#f00").dc(0,0,5);
    for (var i=start, l=end; i<=l; i+=degenerate) {
        var segments = i; // Easier to read than "i"
        var d = Math.pow(segments/end, 0.75) * radius;
        var counter = segments%(degenerate*2) == 0;
        var offset = Math.PI*2 * 1/segments;
        for (var j=0; j<segments; j++) {
            var angle = Math.PI*2 * (j/segments+i*0.002);
            var s = new createjs.Shape(g);
            s.x = Math.sin(angle) * d;
            s.y = Math.cos(angle) * d;
            container.addChild(s);
        }
    }
    container.rotation = 45; // Cuz it looks cooler
}
```

This makes it match about 98%. I brought the result into Photoshop, and with some slight rotation and scale of the generated result, here is my result overlayed over the original (mine is dark red).
http://screens.gskinner.com/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-29%20at%209.55.06%20AM.png

And here is the updated fiddle with the final result.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/sbmaLed1/6/

Comment: I don't think my counter math is right. I might take another stab at it. [Note: Demo and answer have been updated]

Comment: Thanks Lanny for your effort, but it's not showing my effect which i have given url. Please observer the shape of the circle you can easily find out the difference

Comment: Yeah, sorry -- without some idea of what this is based on, that is the best I can do.

Comment: I was able to get a little closer by trending towards the outside. Its still not exact, but more similar: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/sbmaLed1/5/

Comment: Just posted another result, which is even closer. Check out the result http://screens.gskinner.com/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-29%20at%209.55.06%20AM.png and the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/sbmaLed1/6/

Comment: I got the output. Thanks for your reply on the question.
http://jsfiddle.net/jyoshna/tcgefwen/2/

Comment: Here I need some help
http://jsfiddle.net/jyoshna/2hr4rat6/
please check the above url
you can find the Macular Grid functionality, Here you can find two parallel lines in diagonal format.. Here, I need to change the parallel line style format like opposite faces like one should be left , another right...
If you know any thing, please let us know